# Issue with Moving phpmailer Page from Localhost to Server

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I have been developing a page that will automatically send emails from a Gmail account to mail accounts of various origin for specific users of my site.  I have this working perfectly on Localhost.  The mails are received by the users and also deposited in the "Sent Items" of the Gmail account.

However, as soon as I migrate this to the server we are using it no longer works.  The code is as follows :-

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
try
{
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    // 1 = errors and messages
    // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    // GMAIL username
    $mail->Username   = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    // GMAIL password
    $mail->Password   = "P4ssw0rd";
    //Set reply-to email this is your own email, not the gmail account 
    //used for sending emails
    $mail->SetFrom($from);
    $mail->FromName = "XXX";
    $mail->AddReplyTo('xxxxxxx@gmail.com' , 'XXX');
    // Mail Subject
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    //Main message
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
    $mail->Send();    
} 
catch (phpmailerException $e) 
{
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Setting the Debug to 1 on localhost produces the expected errors if something goes wrong.  However, nothing seems to happen on the Server.  Please help.

Comment: Most host providers silence all error output - so you will want to be sure debugging output is not being silenced on your server.  Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before other code to be sure errors are being displayed.  Then, you can test by intentionally adding something that would cause an error - for example, `echo $array['somekey'];` should throw a notice about not being defined.

Comment: Hmmm, I've added this to both the function above and the page that calls the function and in both instances there are no errors found, the page just seems to time out and return an error stating that no date was sent to the server.  If I add "echo" statements into the main code if does not return anything which suggests a problem with actually loading that page, even stranger when changing just one line in the function makes most of the code work.

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug` to 2 or 3 to see what the server has to say - you're probably running into their new auth requirements; see [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: @Synchro, this still doesn't report any errors.  However, when you try to go back into the site shortly after the crash it is taking a very long time to load, which would suggest some sort of server side issue.  Still seems strange that the mail gets sent by losing the "IsSMTP" line, just the sent items doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't call `isSMTP` it will send via the `mail()` function, which submits to your local mail server, which may then fail in the same way later on, and you're probably not monitoring it for bounces, so it only looks like it's working. Your code looks like an old example - make sure you're using latest PHPMailer from github, and if you want exceptions you need to pass `true` in the constructor.

Comment: That's what I was assuming, glad I'm not completely crazy.  lol.  This is def the latest phpmailer from Github and the code above was the newest example of using it with Gmail that I could find, although there wasn't exactly a great selection of Gmail examples.